# CICD Java Application(Maven)

Tags: continuous-integration

How can I create a **Java(Maven)** Application as a **CICD** Project on gitlab with windows and with a shell runner. Is it right manner?  When I search this subject, I see a **java/CICD** Project or a **Maven/CICD** Project , but not a CICD Project where the java aplication which build within maven.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that how you can;

```
image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11

build:
  script: "mvn clean install"
```